# Write a program to label the connected components for an undirected graph

Tags: java, graph, tree, components

"Write a program to label the connected components for an undirected graph.
In other words, all vertices of the first component are given the first component’s
label, all vertices of the second component are given the second
Sec. 11.8 Projects 403
component’s label, and so on. Your algorithm should work by defining any
two vertices connected by an edge to be members of the same equivalence
class. Once all of the edges have been processed, all vertices in a given equivalence
class will be connected. Use the UNION/FIND implementation from
Section 6.2 to implement equivalence classes."

```
/** General Tree class implementation for UNION/FIND */
class ParPtrTree {
    private Integer [] array; // Node array

    public ParPtrTree(int size) {
        array = new Integer[size]; // Create node array
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            array[i] = null;
    }

    /** Determine if nodes are in different trees */
    public boolean differ(int a, int b) {
        Integer root1 = FIND(a); // Find root of node a
        Integer root2 = FIND(b); // Find root of node b
        return root1 != root2; // Compare roots
    }

    /** Merge two subtrees */
    public void UNION(int a, int b) {
        Integer root1 = FIND(a); // Find root of node a
        Integer root2 = FIND(b); // Find root of node b
        if (root1 != root2)
            array[root2] = root1; // Merge
    }

    /** @return The root of curr’s tree */
    public Integer FIND(Integer curr) {
        if (array[curr] == null)
            return curr; // At root
        while (array[curr] != null)
            curr = array[curr];
        return curr;
    }
```

Me and a few friends have been boggling our minds at how to approach this question, it isn't clear how the input is represented, we thought of implementing the general graph structures in Shaffer's Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in Java, doing a breadth first search to organize it as a tree and reverse the pointers so it would fit into this data structure but I'm not sure that all of that random work really applies to what were trying to accomplish.

Has anyone ever had/done this problem before? Our professor didn't touch upon the question itself only had it listed in his homework.

Comment: You've been given code that uses `!=` to compare `Integer` objects?  Bad, bad, bad!  (Will still work if all integers are in -128..127 range, but still bad form.)

Comment: @ajb The part of your comment in parentheses is not necessarily true.

Comment: But @ajb is certainly right.  Whoever wrote this code sample should not be teaching Java.  It's not just "bad form" - it's a fairly common source of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like `ParPtrTree` implements an equivalence relation, although I can't figure out what `Par` and `Ptr` stand for.  `UNION(a,b)` adds the equivalence `a === b` to the relation, and thus anything that `a` and `b` were already equivalent to, now all become equivalent to each other.

Without giving you too many details: I think that the assignment is suggesting simply that: for each node *N* in your graph, find all the nodes *N<sub>i</sub>* for which there's an edge from *N* to *N<sub>i</sub>*, and call UNION(*N*,*N<sub>i</sub>*).  Once that's done, the equivalence classes in the equivalence relation correspond to the connected components of the graph.  How you get those classes out of the `ParPtrTree`, I think you'll need to figure out, but consider using a `HashSet` to keep track of graph nodes you've already done something with.  It would be best if you could add a method to `ParPtrTree` to get some information, because that method would be able to access `array`, but I don't know if you're allowed to do that.

Also, as I mentioned in a comment, using `!=` on `Integer` objects doesn't work, because it compares references and not values.  However, you can't blindly change it to use `equals` because the references could be null.  To see if two `Integer` objects are equal, you need something like

```
a == b || (a != null && a.equals(b))
```

and to test if they're different, use `!` on the whole thing.

Comment: I think I understand most of what you're saying, to clarify ParPtrTree stands for Parent Pointer Tree meaning that every node points to its parent and a node without a parent is the root of a component. The data structure makes sense to me, and the Integer array is meant to hold the index of the positions parent so the index of i's parent is stored in array[i]. I don't understand how I'm supposed to take an undirected graph and form it into a tree with parent pointers. I feel like once I have that, I can just use ParPtrTree's methods to determine components by those that share a root

Comment: @user3634600 I don't think you have to worry about that.  An undirected graph shouldn't have parent pointers.  Conceptually, it could just be a list of edges where each edge is a pair of nodes; or it could be a `Map` that maps each node to a list of nodes that are connected to it.  The thing is, the methods already in `ParPtrTree` create the "tree with parent pointers" for you, and all you have to do is use its `UNION` method on the edges to let it create this.

Comment: We thought of having an array of size n and for each element its the head of a linked list of all its neighbors, I think essentially giving us "Map" as you called it. In what process am I going to Union these nodes together as to form a tree?

Does it not matter since the specific structure or whoever becomes the root doesn't effect the fact that they are in the same component? So if I just continually assign a parent to nodes that dont yet have a parent I will eventually be left with a node that no longer has a node as a neighbor with no parents so it acts as the root of the component?

Comment: So if I have R, A, B, C and D

if D's parent is set to C because C is its neighbor, B's parent is set to A because A is it's neighbor, A's parent is set to R and C's parent is set to R for the same reasons

I essentially have my ParPtrTree?

Thank you for your help thus far!

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, but I think you're too hung up on thinking about this tree and parent nodes.  It's like if I turned on my computer and started thinking about how I would get the electrons to move from one transistor to the next one.  But I don't--I let the computer do its job.  Same here.  Let `ParPtrTree` do its job, which is to set up the parent nodes in the tree, internally.  Just worry about how you're going to feed the edges into it.  That's what OOP is all about.

Comment: But what Union does is Union two components together by connecting their roots, I can't just feed in the edges of a undirected graph by giving the 2 nodes the edge connects and get a tree of parent pointers as a result. I did an example on the board and using UNION it connects nodes to the root of the vertex, it will ignore the fact that the node doesn't have an edge to that root. I don't think I can just use UNION to form the graph into this tree structure that I'm required to use.

Comment: @user3634600 I think you can.  Please read my answer about equivalence relations.  Look up "equivalence relations" in Wikipedia if you're not sure what it means.  The point is, the `ParPtrTree` class is implementing equivalence relations.  The tree thing is just how the equivalence relations were implemented.  You really should be concerned only with the *outward effects*, not how it works on the inside (which is why `ParPtrTree` is a terrible name).  I really do think that if you forget about the tree thing completely, your job will be a lot easier.  Focus on edges and equivalences.